# Run Import database DOS command from Java

Tags: java, import, dos

I am trying to run a database import command from a Java program like this:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = {"imp ASKUL/askul@ASKDB file=askdbinstall.dmp log=askul.log fromuser=askul touser=ASKUL full=N ignore=Y grants=Y indexes=Y;"};
        Process pro;
        try {
            pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error Output is:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "imp ASKUL/askul@ASKDB file=askdbinstall.dmp log=askul.log fromuser=askul touser=ASKUL full=N ignore=Y grants=Y indexes=Y;": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

The file askdbinstall.dmp is present because if I Paster the Same Command in CMD, it is importing the database Dump Quite fine. What is My Mistake?

Added:
From Reimius Suggestion I have also tried this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class Tes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          String [] cmd = {"imp", "ASKUL/askul@ASKDB file=askdbinstall.dmp", 
                "log=askul.log", "fromuser=askul", "touser=ASKUL", 
                "full=N ignore=Y grants=Y indexes=Y;"};
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
     InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
     InputStreamReader ins=new InputStreamReader(in);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ins);
     String data = null;
     while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(data);
     }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
   }
   }
}
```

Output

```
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

No Import is taking place.

Comment: It doesn't find the "imp" program. Make sure it is in the PATH

Comment: I added the Path to the Imp.exe as F:/app/Administrator/product/11.1.0/db_3/BIN/imp.exe but Nothing is Happening, the error is not coming But the Import is Not hapening as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import command `String` is being treated as one single command. Try breaking up the tokens. Also check what is being output from `Process#getErrorStream`:

```
String[] str = {"imp", "ASKUL/askul@ASKDB file=askdbinstall.dmp", 
                "log=askul.log", "fromuser=askul", "touser=ASKUL", 
                "full=N ignore=Y grants=Y indexes=Y;"};

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
BufferedReader in = 
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.err.println(line);
}
```

Aside: `ProcessBuilder` make the use of parameter passing easier.

Comment: Am not getting Any Error but Nothing Is happening, I expect the Import to start Happening :P

Comment: Did you check the process outputs? -especially from [Process.getErrorStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()) ?

Comment: There are no Outputs just : `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Comment: @Stanley You are reading from the `OutputStream`. Did you check the error stream?

Comment: Am Not Sure I Know How to do that #Beginner#

Comment: Replace `getInputStream` with `getErrorStream`